# Why does my trigger not fire?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

**I have the following table:**

```
if object_id(N'dbo.Node') is null
create table dbo.Node
(
    ID bigint identity primary key,
    ParentID bigint null foreign key references Node(ID) on delete no action,
    DateCreated datetime not null,
    LastUpdated datetime not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(500) not null,
);
```

**Now, because SQL Server complains when I try to set the foreign key as a cascaded delete, I have created a trigger to do the work:**

```
create trigger Node_Delete on Node for delete
as
begin
    delete from Node where ParentID in (select id from deleted)
end
```

**Now here's a sample data set:**

```
ID                   ParentID             DateCreated             LastUpdated             Name
520                  1                    2010-01-12 02:26:26.890 2010-01-12 02:26:26.890 Test 1
523                  520                  2010-01-12 02:32:44.777 2010-01-12 02:32:44.777 Test 2
```

**Now let's run this bit of SQL:**

```
delete from Node where ID=520
```

**The node should delete, along with the child node. So why do I get this error?**

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK__Node__ParentID__117F9D94". The conflict occurred in database "mydb", table "dbo.Node", column 'ParentID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key blocks the initial delete, and the trigger never fires. Try an INSTEAD OF trigger that deletes from the furthest decedent on up.

Comment: Bingo.  @OP: Remember that CASCADES are resolved before any AFTER triggers fire, and FOR DELETE is just an alias for AFTER DELETE when using DML triggers.

Comment: I must say it's annoying that SQL Server isn't smart enough to recognise that I might want to enforce internal referential integrity within a single table :(